# mongoose "and or" return no result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to find a record that match with either name or passport and the record is not suspended:

```
Person.find({'$or': [{name: name},
                     {passportNo: passportNo}
                    ], 
             "$and":[{suspended: false}]
            }, function(err, result){
```

I get no record, am I doing it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$and` statement should be at the start and should contain the two separate conditions (record is not suspended) AND (OR statement where name or passport matches)

```
{"$and":[{suspended: false}, {'$or': [{name: name}, {passportNo: passportNo}]}] }
```

*****Update

Here is an updated statement based on the following logic
(name field matches AND suspended is false) OR (passportNo field matches AND suspended is false)

```
{"$or":[{'$and': [{name: name}, {suspended: false}]}, {'$and': [{passportNo: passportNo}, {suspended: false}]}] }
```

does this match the logic you are looking for?

****** Update 2

This query  is now checking if
(the suspended field exists AND its value is false AND the name or passport field matches)
OR (the suspended field does not exist AND the name or passport field matches)

```
   {
'$or': [
   {"$and":[
            { "suspended": { $exists: true, $in: [ false ] } }, 
            {'$or': [{"name": name}, {"passportNo": passportNo}]} ]
     },
    {"$and":[
            { "suspended": { $exists: false } } ,
            {'$or': [{"name": name}, {"passportNo": passportNo}]} ]
     } ]
}
```

Comment: What if the suspended field is not define?

Comment: Your first one is right, the only problem is when the suspended field is not in the database, it will not return any result.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is

> Find all documents where (`name` is X or `passportNo` is Y) and (`suspended` is `false` or not present)

use the following query:

```
{
    "$and" : [
        { "$or" : [
            { "name" : X }, 
            { "passportNo" : Y } 
        ] }, 
        { "$or" : [
            { "suspended" : false }, 
            { "suspended" : { "$exists" : false } } 
        ] }
    ]
}
```

You should simplify your life by setting `suspended` to `false` by default, though, so the query can just be

```
{
    { "$or" : [{ "name" : X }, { "passportNo" : Y } ] }, 
    { "suspended" : false }, 
}
```